# Solr abitrary range facet not working without start parameter

Tags: solr

I am trying to use following snippet from JSON Facet API Guide.

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/query -d '
{
  "query": "*:*",
  "facet": {
    "prices": {
      "type": "range",
      "field": "price",
      "ranges": [
        {
          "from": 0,
          "to": 20,
          "inclusive_from": true,
          "inclusive_to": false
        },
        {
          "range": "[40,100)"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

But I keep getting following error.

```
"error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Missing required parameter: 'start' , path=facet/prices",
    "code":400}}
```

Can anybody please help me what is wrong?

Source : https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_3/json-facet-api.html#arbitrary-range

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using? The `range` key hasn't always been available.

Comment: Solr 8.1.1. Thanks. Got the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Support for arbitrary ranges and the `range` parameter in JSON facets [was added in Solr 8.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13272). You'll need to upgrade to at least 8.3 to get support for providing the intervals as part of the range facet (and to support the `range` key).